# PHP code doesn't work with HTML

Tags: php

I have tried to use different PHP code inside HTML code, but everytime I do, it doesn't work, there is no output. I have also installed the PHP interpreter on Notepad++ but it didn't help.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo 'Hello world!';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're using this how, as `http://localhost` or `file:///`? webserver/php installed also? what does html source reveal, "code"?

Comment: You need to request the php script via a http server. You cannot interpret php inside an editor.

Comment: `PHP interpreter on Notepad++`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I installed the PHP interpreter on Komodo Edit. I'm using it as file:///. On Chrome the above code is displayed.

Comment: If you are not running a personal web server like WAMP or XAMPP, php code will not run, which is what I believe your problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the help:)